# Key does not exist, but only for a single folder

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I'm running into an issue with a folder in an S3 bucket, but I can't figure it out... I'm using the following bash script to keep the 10 most recent builds of our app in an S3 bucket. Every time we kick off the build, it just copies the builds down (1 -> 0, 2 -> 1, etc.) and drops the latest build in folder 9. It works well until I get to folder 9, then I get the error `An error occurred (404) when calling the HeadObject operation: Key "iv/9/" does not exist` even though folder 9 does actually exist.

```
declare -i i=0

for j in `seq 1 9`
do
    echo "Copying build # $j to build # $i"
    aws s3 mv s3://xvaws-builds/iv/$j/ s3://xvaws-builds/iv/$i/
    let i++
done
```

I thought maybe folder 9 was being named something goofy, had some whitespace, etc., but after running 'aws s3 ls s3://myaws-builds/iv/' everything looks good...

The results of the loop look like:

```
Copying build # 1 to build # 0
move: s3://myaws-builds/iv/1/ to s3://myaws-builds/iv/0/
Copying build # 2 to build # 1
move: s3://myaws-builds/iv/2/ to s3://myaws-builds/iv/1/
Copying build # 3 to build # 2
move: s3://myaws-builds/iv/3/ to s3://myaws-builds/iv/2/
Copying build # 4 to build # 3
move: s3://myaws-builds/iv/4/ to s3://myaws-builds/iv/3/
Copying build # 5 to build # 4
move: s3://myaws-builds/iv/5/ to s3://myaws-builds/iv/4/
Copying build # 6 to build # 5
move: s3://myaws-builds/iv/6/ to s3://myaws-builds/iv/5/
Copying build # 7 to build # 6
move: s3://myaws-builds/iv/7/ to s3://myaws-builds/iv/6/
Copying build # 8 to build # 7
move: s3://myaws-builds/iv/8/ to s3://myaws-builds/iv/7/
Copying build # 9 to build # 8
An error occurred (404) when calling the HeadObject operation: Key "iv/9/" does not exist
```

The results of an ls on that directory returns:

```
PRE 0/ PRE 1/ PRE 2/ PRE 3/ PRE 4/ PRE 5/ PRE 6/ PRE 7/ PRE 8/ PRE 9/ 2017-02-06 10:06:51 0
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: The script looks fine to me. The problem has to be on AWS.

Comment: Unrelated, but there is no need to use two variables that could get out of sync. `for((j=1; j<=9; j++)); do`, then use `$((j-1))` where you are currently using `$i`.

Comment: Thought about using S3 versioning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

S3 doesn't actually support folders. Unless you created a pseudo-folder named `iv/9/` via the S3 web console or something, then that "folder" isn't going to actual exist and you will get this error message. I recommend you check if any of those commands are actually doing what you think they are doing.

For example if you created an object in S3 with the key `iv/9/filename.txt`, and another with the key `iv/9/filename2.txt`, then you still don't have a folder named `iv/9/` in your S3 bucket. What you have are two objects that can be found if you filter on the key prefix `iv/9/`

Comment: Ah, that actually makes a lot of sense... Looks like 0-8 were created through the UI and 9 was created through the CLI. I re-created them all through the CLI and used `sync` to copy the objects instead. Thanks for the help.